# ajax auto complete source code change

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have decided to make some changes in source code of ajax autocomplete.But i don know after making changes how can I use that.How to build that and add the newly modified file to ajax library.I need help regarding this.

Comment: A google search should get you some answers.

Comment: I searched but couldn't get anything.. can u pl help??